# Delete all lines that do NOT start with letters or punctuation marks

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

I have a very long textfile in the following format:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:16,700
to use 2 languages.

2
00:00:16,700 --> 00:00:19,600
I was saying that we are going to use 2 languages

3
00:00:19,600 --> 00:00:24,700
...I myself will continue to speak because of time
```

Now I want to delete everything BUT the text, so the result should be:

```
to use 2 languages.
I was saying that we are going to use 2 languages
...I myself will continue to speak because of time
```

What would be the correct regex command? Also a command that would delete all lines containing numbers would work. I am using Sublime Text or regex101.com

Comment: yes, that would be also enough to solve the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/(?:^|\n)\d+\n[\d\:\,\s\->]+/g
```

This seems like a pretty good RegEx. Substitute that with `\n` and you’re left with only the words.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dA8eC2/1).

Answer (score 1):

Both these require *multi-line* and *case insensitive* modes.
They are in-lined in the regex, but can be specified as one of the find options.

The replacement is an empty string.

For punctuation , this uses properties:

```
 # (?im)(?:^[^\p{punct}a-z].*\s*)+

 (?im)
 (?:
      ^ 
      [^\p{punct}a-z] 
      .* 
      \s* 
 )+
```

this one uses POSIX:

```
 # (?im)(?:^[^[:punct:]a-z].*\s*)+

 (?im)
 (?:
      ^ 
      [^[:punct:]a-z] 
      .* 
      \s* 
 )+
```